# Why don't need any server validation when I register a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system

I register a domain in freenom today (I had never done this before) and I was surprised that I did not need any validation from my server side I only register my a domain with my bare ip.

I don't understand why DNS doesn't have any registration or authentication mechanism when I want to assign a domain in a server. I think that someone else would be able to assign a domain in my server before. it's possible avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't avoid that someone points his domain name to your server's IP address.

However, this doesn't really matter in most cases, as all that really happens in this situation is that you can access your server not only with your domain name but also with another. This doesn't make your server any more or less secure, as the security of it doesn't depend at all on any domain names configured.

The only issue might be with web servers, but you can really easy configure any web server to just throw an error if a request comes in for another domain name. But this is also not a security concern, but an issue about copyright  and similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

**Coupling**

Domains and servers are not tightly coupled. You can have a domain that has no server, a domain that has a cluster of servers, a domain where different servers manage web traffic (A records) and email (MX records), and you can have a server that has no domain. Also consider "serverless" computing, which does have servers but you don't control them. In this case you point at a gateway or load balancer.

**Domain Authority**

You're the only person who has access to the domain registrar, so you control where requests for that domain go. In practice your main choices are to use an A record to specify a server by IP or a CNAME record which is essentially an alias for another domain / load balancer / gateway / etc.

**Misuse**

You can't stop other people pointing their domains at your server. You typically have to deal with this at the application layer - for example your web server (Apache / Nginx) should only respond to requests that include your domain, rather than to your IP. If the request is for a domain you don't control you can drop the request, send back an error code, or redirect the requester to another domain.